# Java regex - Extract all float numbers before specific unit in String

Tags: java, regex

I am a newbie in java regex. I would like to know how to extract numbers or float numbers before `%`. For example:

```
"Titi 10% Toto and tutu equals 20X"
"Titi 10.50% Toto and tutu equals 20X"
"Titi 10-10.50% Toto and tutu equals 20X
"Titi 10sd50 % Toto and tutu equals 20X
"Titi 10-10.50% or 10sd50 % Toto and tutu equals 20X
```

Output :

```
10
10.50
10-10.50
10sd50
10-10.50;10sd50
```

My idea is to replace all before and after `"space + number(% or space%)"` by `;` in order to extract all values or group values before `%`. I tried to use that: `replaceAll("[^0-9.]+|\\.(?!\\d)(?!\\b)\\%",";");` = NO SUCCESS

How can I do it?

Comment: Not my downvote, but might be better suited by a parser.  You can start by splitting the string on space, and then examining each word (possibly using a regex) to see it be a) a candidate for retention, and if so, then b) strip off the stuff you don't want.

Comment: Thank you. I know this is a trivial task for Java users but I am not an expert !!! I would like to learn more about that. I try your solution. Thanks a lot Tim

Comment: Next time you post please include the code you have tried.  SO is not a free code writing service and most folks resent questions which show little/no effort but ask for a complex answer.

Comment: `10sd50` is not a number, nor `10-10.50`

Comment: 10sd50 is equivalent to 10 +/- 0.50. I replace all '+/-' by 'sd'.

Comment: Why did you replace `+/-` with `sd`? Was this done by your program, intentionally or unintentionally?

Comment: intentionally. Because it's different from X-Y%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as follows:

- First find all the matches in each string
- Replace the last character(`%`) of each match elements with Blank
- Do as your own formatting.

A java samples is given :

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String regex = "\\d+(\\.?\\d+)?(\\+|\\-|sd)?(\\d+(\\.?\\d+)?)?[ ]*%";
        final String test_str = "\"Titi 10% Toto and tutu equals 20X\"\n"
                + "\"Titi 10.50% Toto and tutu equals 20X\"\n"
                + "\"Titi 10-10.50% Toto and tutu equals 20X\n"
                + "\"Titi 10sd50 % Toto and tutu equals 20X\n"
                + "\"Titi 10-10.50% or 10sd50 % Toto and tutu equals 20X";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        for(String data : test_str.split("\\r?\\n")) {
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);
            while (matcher.find()) {
                System.out.print(data.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end()-1) + " ") ;
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

The above code gives :

```
10 
10.50 
10-10.50 
10sd50  
10-10.50 10sd50
```

You can do anything with these data. 
You can see the Explanations : [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/YL62pB/2)

Comment: Thank you very much Sunkuet. And your external link is very nice :)

Comment: @B.Gees , If the answer helps you, then you can upvote my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This one should do the job:

```
((?:\d+(?:+|-|sd))?\d+(?:\.\d+)\h*%)
```

**Explanation:**

```
(               : start group 1
  (?:           : start non capture group
    \d+         : 1 or more digits
    (?:+|-|sd)  : non capture group that contains + or - or sd
  )?            : end group
  \d+           : 1 or more digits
  (?:           : start non capture group
    \.          : a dot
    \d+         : 1 or more digits
  )             : end group
  \h*           : 0 or more horizontal spaces
  %             : character %
)               : end of group 1
```

The result will be in group 1.

In java you have to double escape, I've not done it here for readability.